# Can’t display PyPlot in Juno

Tags: julia

I have a problem about the plot data on juno using pyplot.

```
using PyCall
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x))
plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
```

After I did "eval all" in Juno, nothing happened.

Is there a solution in solving this problem? 
thanks

Comment: [This thread](http://discuss.junolab.org/t/pyplot-inline-results/145/13) from the Juno boards might help.

Answer (score 4):

`plot`will only return a vector of PyObjects.
To display the figure interactively in Juno use `gcf()` (get current figure).